# Reduce minmax problem to linear problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

A is mxn matrix, c is n vector and b is m vector.
Convert following problem to linear problem
$$max_{x \ge 0} min_{y \ge 0} (c^Tx - y^TAx + b^Ty)$$

I think I can write min to max by just changing sign and it will be as a whole a maximisation problem. But I dont know how to handle the middle term containing both x and y.
Thankyou.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me; Also, kindly explain how you attempted to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: Changing the signs seems to me a good idea. So $\max\limits_{x \ge 0} \max\limits_{y \ge 0} (c^Tx -(-y^TAx) +b^T(-y))=\max\limits_{x \ge 0, y \ge 0} (c^Tx +Ax - b^Ty)$

Comment: @callculus42 where is that y in the second term? also is the problem linear if there is a term containing product of x and y?

Comment: @BullyMaguire It was a typo, sorry: $\max\limits_{x \ge 0, y \ge 0} (c^Tx +y^TAx - b^Ty)$. It is still not linear.

Comment: Is it possible to merge x and y into a single vector somehow to  get same problem?

Comment: @BullyMaguire I've found the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773325). Good luck.